# SQL Server sum changes data type

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm summing some data up using SQL Server 2008.  The data is of type money and it is set to not allow nulls.  When I sum it up the resultant data is money but allowing nulls.  This is an issue when I use the code in C# as money not allowing nulls doesn't equal money allowing nulls, amongst other issues with null allowing data.  What can I do to get around this mess?

My SQL is:

```
SELECT     
    dbo.Subcontracts.SubcontractID, dbo.Subcontracts.AccountNumber, 
    dbo.SubcontractAmounts.ObjectCode, dbo.Subcontracts.AppendId, 
    dbo.Subcontracts.BeginDate, dbo.Subcontracts.EndDate, 
    dbo.Subcontracts.RecipientGrantorId, dbo.Subcontracts.CheckA133, 
    dbo.Subcontracts.CheckDebarment, dbo.Subcontracts.CostshareRequired, 
    dbo.Subcontracts.CostshareAmountRequired, dbo.Subcontracts.CreatedOn, 
    dbo.Subcontracts.CreatedBy, dbo.Subcontracts.ModifiedOn, 
    dbo.Subcontracts.ModifiedBy, dbo.Subcontracts.IsDeleted, dbo.Subcontracts.FARate, 
    dbo.Subcontracts.SubContractAgreementTypeId, dbo.Subcontracts.ContractRiskLevelId, 
    CAST(SUM(dbo.SubcontractAmounts.SubAmount) AS money) AS TotalSubAmount, 
    SUM(dbo.SubcontractPayments.PaymentAmount) AS TotalPaymentAmount, 
    SUM(dbo.SubcontractPayments.AdvanceAmount) AS TotalAdvanceAmount, 
    SUM(dbo.SubcontractPayments.CostshareAmount) AS TotalCostshareAmount, 
    SUM(dbo.SubcontractAmounts.SubAmount - dbo.SubcontractPayments.PaymentAmount) AS UnpaidBalance
FROM          
    dbo.Subcontracts 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.SubcontractAmounts ON dbo.Subcontracts.SubcontractID = dbo.SubcontractAmounts.SubcontractID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.SubcontractPayments ON dbo.SubcontractAmounts.SubcontractAmountID = dbo.SubcontractPayments.SubcontractAmountID
GROUP BY 
    dbo.Subcontracts.SubcontractID, dbo.Subcontracts.AccountNumber, 
    dbo.Subcontracts.AppendId, dbo.Subcontracts.BeginDate, dbo.Subcontracts.EndDate, 
    dbo.Subcontracts.RecipientGrantorId, dbo.Subcontracts.CostshareAmountRequired, 
    dbo.Subcontracts.CreatedOn, dbo.Subcontracts.CreatedBy, 
    dbo.Subcontracts.ModifiedOn, dbo.Subcontracts.ModifiedBy, dbo.Subcontracts.FARate, 
    dbo.Subcontracts.SubContractAgreementTypeId, dbo.Subcontracts.ContractRiskLevelId, 
    dbo.Subcontracts.IsDeleted, dbo.Subcontracts.CheckA133, dbo.Subcontracts.CheckDebarment, 
    dbo.Subcontracts.CostshareRequired, dbo.SubcontractAmounts.ObjectCode
```

This is being pulled into a 3rd party tool called Subsonic. That recognizes the data as nullable which I don't want. Since the code to interact with the data is generated I can't just change it.  I could change the data to non-nullable everywhere I use it but that is not a desired or good solution.

Comment: How can a sum of non-null numbers ever be null?

Comment: include relevant code and examples?

Comment: any left joins in the query with missing data? that's the only way I can see a null getting into that column

Comment: @zmbq a sum of 0 records would be null.

Comment: @zmbq if there are no results from the where statement

Comment: To avoid all of the confusion wouldn't it make `Sense` to post your `C# code, SQL Statement || Both` and to answer your question about `What can I do to get around this mess?` `Answer= DEBUG your CODE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try explicitly converting the result to a non-null value:

```
SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Amount), 0) FROM MyTable
```

Or handle possible `null` values on the C# side.

Comment: Using isnull handled this.  I didn't think about the left join on the table having possible missing records resulting in nulls.

Answer (score 0):

Use [decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75%28VS.80%29.aspx) for your money type, because it will always have some default value. Like:

```
decimal myMoney = 300.5m;
```

If you need to have a nullable type decimal, you can use `decimal?`. Then you can do `myDecimal.HasValue`

Comment: `decimal` can't be null, which is the key problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy for the result to be 0 where you'd otherwise get a null:

```
long result = (long)(dbCommand.ExecuteScalar() ?? 0)
```